# How can I get count of occurrence of a word by Hibernate Search?

Tags: hibernate-search, full-text-indexing

For example, there is a word "apple", I want to know no of times it has occurred in different rows.

Thanks!

> EDIT

I have a database that contains textual data of what people are talking about.
For example: 
People1 : I like apple.
People2 : I like apple and stackoverflow.
Ignoring common words we can see that 
Topic1 is apple which is talked about by 2 people.
Topic2 is stackoverflow which is talked about by 1 people.

I want the indexing engine to fetch all the topics which are talked the most. It is similar to finding trending topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot by default. Full text search is not about counting occurrences, but about finding the most suitable results (`Document`s in Lucene terminology). Also talking about *rows* in this context is misleading. You really need to talk about indexed content/fields.

That said, you can get access to the underlying Lucene resources in Hibernate Search. Among others you can get access to the `IndexReader` which should allow you to get a term frequency for a given term.

Slightly related, there is also a faceting API, but it deals with concrete values.

Really you would have to provide more context about the problem you are trying to solve.